# Tridion 9.5 CoreService publish method fails

Tags: core-service, sites-9.5

Hi I am trying to publish content using core service, I am getting following error

> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source

here is following code I am using to publish

```
_client.Publish(new String[] { id }, pid, purposes.toArray(), PublishPriority.Low, new ReadOptions());
```

not able to understand parameter name: source
could someone please suggest me.

Comment: I can see your 2nd parameter something pid what was that? that should be publishInstruction object. eg. var publishInstruction = new PublishInstructionData  { ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData()};

Comment: Hi @Velu, thanks for response, pid is PublishInstructionData object only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot debugging was able to figure out that on below code

```
_client.Publish(new String[] { id }, pid, purposes.toArray(), PublishPriority.Low, new ReadOptions());
```

I was passing string array on purposes i.e. `Live`, `Live1`

But Publish method on core-service is expecting `id` instead of purpose string.

Previously I was fetching purpose string by below line of code

```
bpt.TargetTypes.Select(targetTypes => targetTypes.Purpose);
```

but when changed it to

```
bpt.TargetTypes.Select(targetTypes=> targetTypes.Id);
```

then Publish method doesn't fail and also push the item to Publish Queue.

Comment: Nice that you found a work-around, but it should work with Target purposes too. Can you provide a full Stack Trace (obtained from Tridion Event Log). That will provide more information of how/where it fails when you provide Target purposes.

Answer (score 3):

The error happens if you call a Linq statement on a null object. The only Linq statement in your code is ToArray(). My guess is that the variable purposes is null.

Comment: Hi @Quirijn, thanks for response, but I have added null check on the code and tried to debug code, purposes.ToArray(), it is throwing error even it has values.

Comment: After lot debugging just found when we pass target id, it works, but when we pass purpose array it just throws error: Value cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

Publish Page coreservice example:

```
// Publish the page
var publishInstruction = new PublishInstructionData
{
     ResolveInstruction = new ResolveInstructionData()
};
PublishTransactionData[] unpublishTransactions = core.Publish(new[] { pageUri }, publishInstruction, destinationTargetUrisOrPurposes, PublishPriority.Normal,new ReadOptions());
```